# Why do I have to have double quotes inside single quotes in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

Can someone explain why I must embed the double quotes within single quotes in my Webpack configuration below?  Why does it not work to just use double quotes?

```
module.exports = merge(prodEnv, {
  NODE_ENV: '"development"',
  API: '"http://localhost:8080"'
});
```

My app fails to load if I remove the single quotes, which seems really odd.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This webpack plugin is going to be doing *interpolation* in your code. In other words, it will be replacing, at build time, `process.env.NODE_ENV` with whatever you have there.

So your code goes from `console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)` to `console.log("development")`. If you left out the single quotes it would become `console.log(development)`, which would fail since there is no variable `development`.

Comment: It wouldn't even get that far, the config would fail with a SyntaxError first.

Comment: Not true. He's asking why you can't do: `NODE_ENV: "development"`

Comment: Huh, you're completely right, my answer is wrong. *I* understood the question wrong. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Makes sense.  Thanks!